$p+ip$ pairing in a spinless fermion system with attractive interaction
In this article (Section III.D), the following model of spinless fermions on the honeycomb lattice is considered:
$$
H = -t \sum_{\langle ij \rangle}
(c^\dagger_i c_j + h.c.)
- V \sum_{\langle ij \rangle} n_i n_j
+ \mu \sum_i (n_i - \delta)
$$
where $n_i = c^\dagger_i c_i$ and $\mu$ is the chemical potential that controls the average particle density $\langle n_i \rangle = \delta$. It is stated without reference that

... the general argument that a spinless fermion system with
attractive interactions supports $p + ip$ pairing.

Here $p+ip$ pairing means the following real space pairing pattern on the honeycomb lattice
$$
\frac{\Delta_2}{\Delta_1}
= \frac{\Delta_3}{\Delta_2}
= \frac{\Delta_1}{\Delta_3}
= e^{2\pi i/3}
$$
where $\Delta_a = \langle{c_i c_{i+r_a}} \rangle$, $r_a (a = 1,2,3)$ are the three nearest neighbor vectors (in clockwise order). What is the "general argument" mentioned in the article?


A spinless fermion system with attractive interactions supports p+ip
pairing.

In a spinless fermion system, there is no spin degree of freedom, which means the pairing must occur purely in the spatial part of the wavefunction. Also, due to the Pauli exclusion principle, we require that the overall - here just spatial wavefunction of two fermions be antisymmetric. Combining these two facts already excludes the possibility of symmetric type pairings such as $s$, $d$,... and are left with $p$, $f$, ... type pairings.
Now, a key fact is that a Time-Reversal Symmetry Breaking (TRSB) phase is always energetically favorable within a 2D representation of the spatial group describing the system of spinless fermions in 2D (derived as eq. 10 of
[1]). One heuristic way to think about this is that the TRSB state, e.g., p+ip, provides an isotropic (in the sense that the magnitude of the superconducting gap is uniform in all directions in momentum space) pairing potential, which minimizes the free energy across the Fermi surface.
Knowing this, the only thing one needs to check is: what is the spatial symmetry group and its representation for a given lattice. If the group has only 2D representations (e.g. square lattice), then we immediately know that only TRSB superconducting phases are allowed -> and can confirm that it is the p+ip pairing that minimizes the energy (at least on the mean-field level), while if a symmetry group allows for 1D representations as well (e.g. one dim f representations of a D6 group) - then more analysis is required to determine, which phase will dominate in the phase diagram. The presence of additional symmetries like P-H symmetry, sublattice symmetry, inversion symmetry can help make more general statements here.
For more precise calculations and exact considerations, see the analysis by
Cheng et al.[1] - primarily section III, and the discussion of the square and triangular lattice. Since you are working with a hexagonal lattice, i would expect that things are going to be very similar to the analysis for a triangular lattice (same D6 symmetry group).
1: https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.81.024504
